# Beginner - How to make CSS changes?

Tags: theming

I have very little Drupal experience and recently inherited a Drupal 6 site. I want to make some CSS changes, but from what I can tell all the CSS is in /home/saybrook/drupal/sites/default/files/css, where there are a bunch of CSS files that seemed to be cached. If I make changes to those files, they'll probably be lost eventually.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

1. Find out what theme you're using (visit /admin/build/themes)
2. Find the files in your Drupal installation for that theme (if it's a core theme it'll be under /themes, if contrib it'll likely be in /sites/all/themes)
3. Change what you need to.

If it's a core theme, don't edit it (you'll lose the changes when you next update Drupal core) - create a [subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) instead.

The files in /sites/default/files/css are the optimised files produced when CSS aggregation is turned on; for development you'll want to disable that (/admin/settings/performance), or you'll need to clear the css cache every time you make a change.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is still in development I would recommend you turn off performance caching at /sites/all/themes completely until your CSS changes are made.

You will then want to locate the .css files of the custom theme you uploaded, which would either be in the /themes folder or the /sites/all/themes folder.